# Resources from jar available from source code but not in xml

Tags: android, jar

I've compiled [SettingsLib](http://aospxref.com/android-13.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/) and copied jar to my project: `frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/javac/SettingsLib.jar`

Jar contains [this drawable](http://aospxref.com/android-13.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/drawable/avatar_selector.xml) that I would like to use. It's accessible in Java code:

```
int id = com.android.settingslib.R.drawable.avatar_selector;
```

but when I try to use it in xml files:

```
android:drawable="@drawable/avatar_selector"
```

**it fails** due to:
`AAPT: error: resource drawable/avatar_selector not found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out myself. The procedure is ugly so no wonder there is no info about it from Google developers, maybe they were ashamed of the process and preferred to keep this for themselves :D If there is better way to do that then please let me know.

First of all if you just build Android with "make" you will not have aar files in out directory, just the jars (maybe with some small exceptions). What you need to do is to "make " e.g. "make SettingsLib" (weird but this is how it currently is), this will additionally generate aar here:

```
out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/SettingsLib.aar
```

but it's not the end of the story ... If you unzip and compare SettingsLib.jar with SettingsLib.aar you will notice that jar contains:

```
META-INF, androidx, com
```

while aar contains:

```
META-INF, AndroidManifest.xml, classes.jar, R.txt
```

but ... if you open "magic" aar that Google put into source code e.g. `prebuilts/sdk/current/aaos-libs/car-apps-common.aar` you will notice that it additionally contains **res** directory:

```
META-INF, res, AndroidManifest.xml, classes.jar, R.txt
```

so what you need to do is to unzip generated aar (in this case SettingsLib.aar), then copy paste resources (in this case frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res), zip the files once again, change extension to .aar and finally resources will be available also from the xml files.

You might also encounter some problems with duplicated strings or binary resources conflicting with the normal ones and you might need to clean project when rebuilding but other than that it should work.

Comment: Yeah, but this stuff is generally done using Gradle. Googlers have a `build.gradle` for each system component, then it's enough to build/assemble individual modules and you get the complete AAR in `SettingsLib/build/outputs/aar/SettingsLib-release.aar`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but there are no gradle files for SettingsLib, at least in AOSP code. Do you know if Google keeps them in different repositories? Are they publicly available somewhere? If not do you know why?

Comment: They don't expose it to the public because it's used for development. Ofc, the development process of a googler that has access to proprietary dependencies will setup the `build.gradle` accordingly, which will be invalid for the user that can only access prebuilt dependencies. Some apps contain a `build.gradle` some not. I just end up creating `build.gradle` myself for each module that don't have it by looking in its `Android.bp`/`Android.mk` file. It's not difficult especially for SettingsLib, which depends entirely on `androidx` and `framework.jar` (containing the `@hide` methods ofc).

Comment: Check out this repository. This guy made the Settings app built entirely by gradle. It's for Android 11, but the principle is the same.

https://github.com/siren-ocean/Settings/blob/master/SettingsLib/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks, actually I've did the same, so I've created build.gradle myself but I wouldn't say that it was simple. For example the guy you're referring to had to create build.gradle not only for SettingsLib but also for ActionBarShadow and other stuff, so it required some work.

Comment: Expected, but SettingsLib is the easy one. No native stuff, protos and other specific stuff, just point to src and res dirs and link dependencies together. It requires some manual work but no more than this. In my case I needed some libs from SettingsLib.